# D3 Brush Event Not Working Correctly

Tags: d3.js, svg, brush

In D3 I am working on customizing and adding to @Rengel's timeline (link shown in JS Fiddle.

I've successfully created a similar timeline based on tracks, and it also allows users to filter project data based on checkbox values. Each piece of data now has a tooltip, and there are letters from another dataset populating underneath the projects in the same svg container. Now finally I want to add a brush like this one - wrobstory's from the blocks website.

I have only recently started to work on brush events so I am very much a noob, which is why I am unsure how I am going wrong. There is a JS Fiddle I created at: https://jsfiddle.net/rootseire/2vq8028o/2/ which shows everything working before the brush gets called. When I select a section of the timeline, the brush appears, it calculates indexes and extent. But it changes the y state of the year and the year text then transitions down the page.

I have been trying to see why this is happening, but I think I need to step back from the code as it might be just that I am not referencing the correct element. Here is the code for when the mouse pointer drags over the interface:

```
vis.on('mousedown', function(){
 brush_elm = vis.select(".brush").node();
 new_click_event = new Event('mousedown');
 new_click_event.pageX = d3.event.pageX;
 new_click_event.clientX = d3.event.clientX;
 new_click_event.pageY = d3.event.pageY;
 new_click_event.clientY = d3.event.clientY;
 brush_elm.dispatchEvent(new_click_event);
  });
```

But I think it might have something to do with the .points selector. How can I make the brush target the x-axis, the project rectangles and the letters together?

Thanks in advance,
P

Comment: your JSFiddle doesnt work

Comment: Hi @thatOneGuy I also set it up here: http://o-em.org/d3/timeline.html

Comment: kind of no use unless you expect me to put all your code together from the source files. Better if you get a working fiddle together

Comment: I got a working fiddle now: https://jsfiddle.net/rootseire/2vq8028o/12/

Comment: Any input on this? Still haven't been able to see where it is going wrong!

Comment: Still no luck with this issue, i've tried to target the x-axis but no luck with it yet

Comment: Hi, still have the fiddle here  jsfiddle.net/rootseire/2vq8028o/12 Any help on how to get the brush working properly would be great, thank you